# jQuery: load response Document into div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get an asyc response from the server that contains an HTML that I would like to display:

```
    $( document ).ready( function ()
    {
       var options = 
       {
        success: showResponse,
        error: errorHandler,
        type: 'post'
       }; 

       // bind to the form's submit event 
       $('#captureForm').submit(function() 
       {
           $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
           return false; 
       });
   });

   function showResponse(responseDoc, statusText)
   {
       $('#output').html( responseDoc );
   }
```

Where #output is a div where I would like the response document to be injected. The above code does not do the trick.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

-Raj

Comment: if you alert `responseDoc` are you getting something?

Comment: Yes: "[object Document]"

If I follow the Document object in firebug, it is an XML doc that has the DOM (sub)tree I want to inject into my div.

Answer (score 0):

it might be a problem with options, try moving them into the function.

Comment: Aaron,
Thanks for the response. I can see showResponse() being called with an XML DOM object, so the form submission part is OK. The question really is, how do I inject (or append) this DOM into the div called output

Comment: Does the #output div exist and is there a response? Are you returning XML instead of HTML?

Comment: I have <div id="output"></div>. The response content type is XML since I am returning a <div> as the root element from the server.